# What is the meaning of ' I don't want him in the room.'

Tags: grammar

I think the sentence means that I don't want the situation that he is in the room. 
Am I right?
I want to know the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: Your understanding of the meaning is correct.  You do not want him (to be) in the room.

Comment: @TRomano     I really want to thank you for teaching me right English. I always thank you whenever you answer my question.

Comment: You are welcome. We are here to be helpful to those who wish to learn.

Answer (score 1):

This is the equivalent of "I want this person to not be inside the room."

Both indicate that your preference is for him to leave.